# Inserting bytes base 64 encoded string into sql database column

Tags: ios, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a string that is data bytes base64EncodedString from iOS which is an extremely long string

```
let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

I am calling a .NET Method from my ios that will call a stored procedure to insert these bytes into the database.

Here is my .NET Method, notice the data type I have set it VarChar for @Images

```
public List<Images> PostLandGradingImages(List<Images> landingCells)
        {

            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("PostLandGradingImages", connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        for (int i = 0; i < landingCells.Count; i++)
                        {
                            command.Parameters.Clear();

                            SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@Job_No", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                            parameter1.Value = landingCells[i].jobNo;
                            parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                            command.Parameters.Add(parameter1);

                            SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                            parameter2.Value = landingCells[i].imageBytes;
                            parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                            command.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return landingCells;
            }

            return landingCells;
        }
```

Here is my Image Class, notice my imageBytes is defined as a string:

```
public class Images
    {
        public string jobNo { get; set; }
        public string imageBytes { get; set; }
    }
```

Now the data type for the column I am trying to insert to in my sql database is nvarchar(MAX)

But when my stored procedure runs, the record does not get inserted:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PostLandGradingImages] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Job_No varchar(MAX) = NULL,
    @Image varchar(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO LandGradingImages (Job_No, ImageBytes) VALUES (@Job_No, @Image)
END
```

Now I am unable to debug the .NET code, but I have a feeling I am not setting the data types correctly, my question is what data types do I need to set to insert bytes in base64EncodedString to a database column? If I pass in the string "AAAA" everything works, but not with my bytes.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Is your SP solid  ? Did you try executing the SP from SSMS by passing 2 test values ? Does it get saved ? Also switch to `nvarchar` and see what happens

Comment: Also, remember, SQL server has a varbinary type in which you can store byte array

Comment: Yes I have tried varbinary type, but it didn't work, I had varbinary type set in the column, stored procedure and stored procedure call in my method, that didn't work with my string. Yes my stored procedure works with the string "AAAAA"

Comment: if you use varbinary in db, you have to pass a byte array, not a string.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your exception- `catch` block and inspect what the inner exception/message is

Comment: I cant put a breakpoint and run locally, ill try returning a string instead and return the error if there is one.

Comment: What is stopping you from putting a breakpoint  and inspecting the exception object ? Your current `catch` block is not logging exception. You must log the exception or `throw` so somewhere down the line it can be logged

Comment: Just change `return landingCells;` inside `catch` clause to `throw e;` and set breakpoint on it, it will show both exception message and details. Then, include it in your question.

Comment: u can use `Convert.FromBase64String` to convert it into `byte[]` and then save that as `VarBinary` into Sql

Comment: "bytes in base64EncodedString"...the "String" bit gives you a clue, the data you're dealing with is **not** a byte array, it's a string. So you can either just store it as a string, or convert it to bytes first.

Comment: I've tried converting them back to byte[] `byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(landingCells[i].imageBytes);` and changed all my data types to VarBinary and it still does not work